# os.popen() variables

Tags: python, popen, os.system

So i have this application thats rather complicated...
To keep it short this is the main things you should know:

```
file_name = raw_input("Name your file:").lower()

os.popen(sudo tcpdump -c5 -vvv -w "file_name" host wiki or host wiki2)
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Can i get a fix?
Thanks,
Pastelinux

edit1:
Alright this is what i have now, but its not working, any pointers on how to fix?

`import subprocess, os, sys`

`filename = raw_input('File name:').lower`

`pipe = os.popen("sudo tcpdump -c5 -w", 'filename')`

`pipe = popen("sudo tcpdump -c5 -w", shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout`

Comment: enclose your `os.popen` argument in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `os.popen', you should use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

I am assuming this (a string):

```
sudo tcpdump -c5 -vvv -w "file_name" host wiki or host wiki2
```

is your command.

Since we just need to call tcpdump and not get any output from it, we use [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

```
>>> subprocess.call(your_command.split())
```

Of course why it is not working depends on what the error is, but this is how you should go about it. If you can update the answer with your error, then it can be clear.

Comment: the error is more of, it allows me input the raw data for "file_name" but it doesn't actually save it.

Comment: Let me look into the subprocess module.

Comment: Yes, you should. The documentation on the Python site is good, but here is another link for further reading: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is you don't pass a string as your command. Fixed call to `popen()`:

```
os.popen('sudo tcpdump -c5 -vvv -w {0} host wiki or host wiki2'.format(file_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running newer versions of Python, then use subprocess module.

See the replacement details of os.popen at :

- http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3

It says: On Unix, os.popen2, os.popen3 and os.popen4 also accept a sequence as the command to execute, in which case arguments will be passed directly to the program without shell intervention.

```
pipe = os.popen("cmd", 'r', bufsize)
==>
pipe = Popen("cmd", shell=True, bufsize=bufsize, stdout=PIPE).stdout
```

Comment: Thank you, ill look into the subprocess module